# Showing progress of gl calculations in qt

Tags: qt, opengl, parallel-processing

I have a process that is doing some heavy maths with gl rather than the cpu (gl/gpu is so far doing approximatly 100x faster than cpu) but still it is about a minute for usual problem sizes to be ready, so I wanted a nice progress bar to know how long it will take.

So I set up my classes to inherit from `QObject` and have a signal `currentProgress(int)` that is emitted every once in a while.
Unfortunately my program freezes during the calculation so no progress is visible.
I found the solution in calling `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` which gave me another problem.
During this call a repaint of the whole window is triggered which results in my calculation being called in an infinite recursion, because it is itself triggered by the paint event.

Now all this problems are signals that tell my programming intuition slot that I probably misdesigned something, so I ask you what is the default way to have a refreshing progress bar in qt?

Also note: When I want to push the calculation into another thread I probably need to create a new GL context or at least move the existing one over. So if that is the way to go, might someone explain to me how to achieve this in qt?

**EDIT**

To make things more clear I am not drawing to the QGLWidget but using a FBO.
Probably it is the best to use an own context for the calculations but I don't know if it is the right way to go.

**New Information**

So I tried to follow your advice but stumbled upon a problem.
A `QGLContext` seems to must have been connected to a screen/gui object so I cannot create one offscreen.

Further I cannot make the `QGLWidget` current in the other threads. It returns the error `QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.` Further all entries I read about that were people with the same problem like me: They wanted to do renderings in another thread and did not find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> During this call a repaint of the whole window is triggered which results in my calculation being called in an infinite recursion, because it is itself triggered by the paint event.

Then you should not be triggering your calculations in the paint event. If the window is the OpenGL window (ie: the GPGPU stuff renders to the window), then you should hide it for the duration of the computations. If it's not the OpenGL window, then refreshing it should not be provoking the computations.

Unless you are using OpenGL to actually draw something, you should be using an off-screen render target. Basically, you create a GL window, then create a new context that shares objects with that using [WGL_ARB_pbuffers](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_pbuffer.txt) (or the GLX equivalent, depending on your GUI system). This is an off-screen render target. Then you destroy the original window.

As for threading, don't forget: even if you have two GL contexts, you only have one GPU. So if you're using OpenGL to draw to a window, and OpenGL to do some computations, this may not all work out.

Comment: You are right about the recursion, it was the mainreason for me to ask although I knew what the answer would be. But the way you describe sounds not very platformindipendent to me. Also note that all my calculations are offscreen as I edited in my question.

Comment: @Nobody Why shouldn't this be platform-independent, considering that Qt even has a class for pbuffer management (`QGLPixelBuffer`)?

Comment: @Christian: A talked about the wgl functions that are windows specific. I also saw the QT Class but it also needs a current context in its thread but I don't get the context over.

Answer (score 2):

A [setUpdatesEnabled(false);](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop) on the painting widget may help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes putting this into a own thread is the way to go. QGLWidget provides the following member functions:

```
void QGLWidget::makeCurrent()
void QGLWidget::doneCurrent()
```

Call them from the processing thread apropriately. `setUpdatesEnables(false);` prevents usual signal processing to trigger a redraw.

BTW: Do I know you from the newsgroup *comp.graphics.api.opengl*? There's a "Nobody" active there, too. Take a look at my user profile to know who I am there.

Comment: That looks like a solution, I will try it. But as I am new to QT the next question for me is: How do I spawn the calculations in a seperate thread? Offtopic: As far as I know I am not on this news-group, but who knows what my evil twin is doing? ^^

Comment: @Nobody: Derive from QThread a class that takes a pointer to the QGLWidget instance in the constructor. In the thread's run() member function call glwidget->makeCurrent(); do your processing and finish with a glwidget->doneCurrent();

Comment: @Nobody: Nicol Bolas suggested using a PBuffer. If PBuffers are available I'd say so, too.

Comment: I don't see why I should use a PBuffer over the FBO. What would be the advantage? Sure I want platformindependence but I think the hardware that only supports PBuffers is way too outdated for the things I am doing.

Comment: @Nobody: A PBuffer comes without any window attached. It's an offscreen drawable you can use without interfering with anything on the screen.

Comment: Do I need to attach a window to a FBO? I mean it is offscreenrendering too.

Comment: @datenwolf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2802/discussion-between-nobody-and-datenwolf)

Comment: I thought Qt doesn't allow to call any methods of GUI classes from another than the main thread.

Comment: @Chrisian Rau: Right that is my main problem now.